# How to solve this linear algebra problem using mathematical induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

please consider this question:

> Let $S,T$, be two linear transformations such that $ST-TS=I$. Prove that $ST^n-T^nS=nT^{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider your base case ($n=1$): $ST^1-T^1S=1T^{1-1}$. Well we know that $ST-TS = I$ and the right side of the base case is $T^0 = I$ so the base case holds.

Let's assume that the statement is true for some value $k$ and try to prove it is true for $k+1$. This means that $ST^k-T^kS=kT^{k-1}$. Let's rearrange things a little to get

$$ST^k=T^kS+kT^{k-1}$$

We want $ST^{k+1}$ so it is natural to multiply on the right by $T$ so let's do that. We then have

$$ST^{k+1} = T^kST+kT^k.$$

However, from the base case we know that $ST = TS+I$. Can you see how to wrap this up?

Answer (score 2):

Let $[S,T]=ST-TS$. By hypothesis $[S,T]=I$. Suppose that $$[S,T^n]=nT^{n-1}$$ Then 
$$\begin{align}[S,T^{n+1}]&=ST^{n+1}-T^{n+1}S\\&=STT^{n}-TT^nS\\&=STT^n+T(ST^n-T^nS)-TST^n\\&=(ST-TS)T^n+T[S,T^n]\end{align}$$

That is, it is always true that $$[S,T^{n+1}]=[S,T]T^n+T[S,T^n]$$

In fact, by the same token as above $$[S,T^{k+n}]=[S,T^k]T^n+T^k[S,T^n]$$